# How to be sure to get all degrees of heading with CLLocationManager when turn device?

Tags: swift, cllocationmanager

I work on a compass app but, I have the impression that the performances are not at the maximum : when I turn my device quickly, 
some degrees are not displayed. Is so fast for the device. On the basic compass app provided on iOS, I think this problem is not present for example.

A screen shot:

[image: Screen of app]

My LocationManager class:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation
import Combine

class LocationManager: NSObject, CLLocationManagerDelegate, ObservableObject {

  var locationManager: CLLocationManager
  var objectWillChange = PassthroughSubject<Void, Never>()

  @Published var heading: Double {
    willSet {
      objectWillChange.send()
    }
  }

  override init() {
    heading = 0
    locationManager = CLLocationManager()
    super.init()
    locationManager.delegate = self
    locationManager.desiredAccuracy = kCLLocationAccuracyBest
    locationManager.startUpdatingHeading()
    locationManager.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
  }

  func locationManager(_ manager: CLLocationManager, didUpdateHeading newHeading: CLHeading) {
    self.heading = Double(round(1 * newHeading.trueHeading) / 1)
  }
}
```

My Arrow class:

```
import SwiftUI
import CoreLocation

struct Arrow: View {

  var locationManager = CLLocationManager()
  @ObservedObject var heading: LocationManager = LocationManager()

  var body: some View {
    VStack {
      Image("arrow")
        .resizable()
        .aspectRatio(contentMode: .fit)
        .frame(width: 300)
        .rotationEffect(.degrees(-heading.heading))
        .animation(Animation.easeOut(duration: 0.2))
      Text(String(heading.heading.stringWithoutZeroFraction + "°"))
        .font(.system(size: 60))
        .fontWeight(.light)
    }
  }
}
```

I don't know if is possible to resolve this problem ? I think that if I solve this problem I could then solve more easily the problem of the arrow which makes a turn after the 360 ​​°